# Starting a Thin cluster on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, bundler, thin

I have a ruby app on my machine that I'm trying to deploy with a batch script.  I've got everything up to the server handled.  This is what I'm using:

```
cd to/path/of/app
thin start -p 3001
```

This works.

```
cd to/path/of/app
thin start --servers 3
```

As per http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/usage/, does not work.  I get an error "lib/thin/runner.rb:142:in 'parse!': invalid option: --servers"

Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 88 in `lib/thin/runner.rb` it says `# Daemonizing not supported on Windows` :(

Comment: Ah, I should have looked there.  Bummer deal.  Any idea how I can get multiple instances up as part of the batch script?