# Starting multiple instances of Thin Server on Windows with a batch script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, batch-file, capistrano, thin

I'm writing a script to automatically deploy a ruby on rails application in Windows.  I have everything automated except for the thin cluster startup; it turns out that daemonizing is not supported in Windows so I cannot use the -servers command when calling thin.

A previous question I posted: [Starting a Thin cluster on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094239/starting-a-thin-cluster-on-windows)

I'm now looking for an alternative approach to getting three instances up programatically.  Does anyone know how I might be able to accomplish this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tried starting `thin start` three times?

Comment: yeah; I can't do that from the script because calling "thin start" holds up the script until the process ends, so anything after that (other thin starts) is pretty much unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` is your friend

read `help start` and try this

```
start /b thin start
```

and read again `help start` and play with other options